# using nested group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Given the following toy example:

```
set.seed(200)
h<-data.frame(T1=sample(0:100,size = 20),ID=sample(c("A","B","C","D"),size=20,replace=T),yr=sample(c(2006:2010),size = 20,replace=T))
```

How can I

- calculate the proportion of ID having more than 1 instance per year
- Create a variable that increments for each ascending value of T1 per ID and year
- Subtract each instance T1(2) from T1(1) and T1(3) from T1(2) etc for each ID

I figured out the first one:

```
h %>% group_by(yr,ID) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% summarise(n2=sum(n>1),n3=n(),n4=n2/n3)
```

Now, to the last two questions - this is the desired output:

```
 T1 ID   yr      Inc.var   diff
1  92  A 2006        1       6
2  98  A 2006        2       0
3  41  B 2006        1       0 
4  26  C 2006        1       71
5  97  C 2006        2       0
6  11  D 2006        1       56
7  67  D 2006        2       0
8   9  B 2008        1       44
9  53  B 2008        2       4
10 57  B 2008        3       19
11 76  B 2008        4       0
12 33  D 2008        etc    etc
13 48  A 2009
14 58  A 2009
15 99  A 2009
16 52  B 2009
17 80  B 2009
18 13  B 2010
19 64  B 2010
20 21  C 2010
```

Comment: It would help if you supplied the desired output for your sample input. It's also best to focus on one question at a time and be specific about the programming problem you are facing. Show any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself and describe why they are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved the last two questions:

```
j <- h %>% group_by(ID,yr) %>% arrange(T1) %>% mutate(diff=lead(T1)-T1,inc.var=seq(length(T1))) %>% arrange(yr)
```